# Can Kong OSS 2.5.X accepts unauthenticated call?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I am new to Kong and would like to know if Kong OSS v2.5.X can accept unauthenticated API call? I can see that v3.0 can do this but can't find the info for v.2.5.X.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Kong will perform no authentication on proxied requests upstream. To enable authentication you would need to apply an authentication plugin such as basic auth.